# How do I verify ansible playbook deleted a file?

Tags: linux, ansible

So I have an ansible playbook that deletes a file.

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: true
  tasks:
    - name: Copy file with owner and permissions
      file:
        path: /etc/logrotate.d/logrotate_file
        state: absent
```

How do I verify that the delete actually happened using another playbook?

Comment: checking file is  deleted using another playbook may not be needed because your original task would fail if if could not delete the file.

Comment: We have a protocol to have a role that validates what we have done and that is why I wanted this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

So what I did was employ the stat ansible module to capture and register the results and then employ debug module to report the message.

Note that this can actually be made better if we use the assert module.

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: true
  tasks:
    - name: register the value
      stat:
        path: /etc/logrotate.d/logrotate_file
      register: __sur_logfile


    - name: Message when it is True
      debug:
        msg: "The suricata Logrotate job is set up"
      when: __sur_logfile.stat.exists == true



    - name: Message when file does not exist (when values is false)
      debug:
        msg: "the job is not there"
      when: __sur_logfile.stat.exists == false
```